# K12 Lesson plan

Tags: education

I just have finished my first year teaching math in middle school and I am not satisfied with my work mainly because I think my lesson time organization is inefficient. In my school we are having 90 minutes lessons and I teach students from 11 to 15 years old.

How do you organize your lesson time (share time between, homework corrections, introduction of new concepts, exercises, research activities...)

Thank you for sharing your experience,
Eric

Comment: To give a reasonable advice, we would have to know many details. What exactly do you consider to be "inefficient" ? I do not have many students (unfortunately), but I always try to motivate them by demonstrating interesting examples , usually teachers have not the time to do that.

Comment: While not really off topic here, you should probably ask this on [matheducators.se] instead.

Comment: inefficient in a way that I often think the student understood and then during exercise and tests I realize they have not. I also think my lesson plan change too much and they are lost.